# Correct way to install Pentaho Kettle from existing system or scratch

Tags: pentaho

What is the correct way to install Pentaho Kettle 4.0.1 
Intent is to only install the component to create and run kettle jobs\transformations

It is installed on one of the machines. I took the .exe package from that m\c and installed it on my new system.
I also copied the DataIntegration folder from that machine. But when it starts, it complains about missing\invalid license.

Where I need to copy the license file. Also if I don't want to copy anything from an existing system, what is the right way to install it from scratch

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) 4.0 is *2 years old*. The current release is 5.0. 
As to how to install it.. You can find the source code here: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/5.0.1-stable/
Download the zip file, extract it, done. To run, click on Spoon.bat in the folder you just extracted. Spoon will handle your jobs and transformations.